# Show search term from google site search in URL on a Joomla 3 site for Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, joomla3.0, google-custom-search

I have a Joomla 3 Website with (paid) Google Site Search on it. A search shows the results on the same page in a module without changing the url (no q=keyword or so). That works perfectly.
But I want to track the search results in Google Analytics. To do that it seems the keyword has to be shown in the url, how can I do that?
I tried to add this code to the analytics code, but still it didn't work:
analytics.js: ga('send', 'pageview', '/search_results.php?q=keyword');

Here's the website i'm talking about: [Kostümverleih Kaiser](http://www.kostuemverleih-kaiser.ch)

Help is very appreciated!

This is my searchbox so far:

```
<div id="cse-search-form" style="width: 100%;">Loading</div>
<script src="//www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
google.load('search', '1', {language: 'de', style: google.loader.themes.V2_DEFAULT});
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
  var customSearchOptions = {};
  var orderByOptions = {};
  orderByOptions['keys'] = [{label: 'Relevance', key: ''} , {label: 'Date', key: 'date'}];
  customSearchOptions['enableOrderBy'] = true;
  customSearchOptions['orderByOptions'] = orderByOptions;
  var imageSearchOptions = {};
  imageSearchOptions['layout'] = 'google.search.ImageSearch.LAYOUT_POPUP';
  customSearchOptions['enableImageSearch'] = true;
  var customSearchControl =   new google.search.CustomSearchControl('016730512287540754301:jb0a5lrvf3y', customSearchOptions);
  customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.FILTERED_CSE_RESULTSET);
  var options = new google.search.DrawOptions();
  options.setSearchFormRoot('cse-search-form');
  options.setAutoComplete(true);
  customSearchControl.setAutoCompletionId('016730512287540754301:jb0a5lrvf3y+qtype:1');
  customSearchControl.draw('cse', options);
}, true);
// ]]>
// ]]></script>
```

Maybe there is a way to send the search to Google Analytics as an Event with the Keyword as proposed in the first answer?

Comment: I got a bit further: Now Analytics shows this in the Site Search:
/search_results.php?q=keyword
But how can I replace the "keyword" with the keyword that was entered?

Comment: Is Javascript an option for you - document.getElementById('gsc-i-id1').value would give you the text in the searchbox. You'd need to pass this to the track pageview call.

Comment: Thx! This sounds good, but i don't know how to include it. I added some infos in the question.